# How to create custom bullet/number formatting in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, formatting

I'm creating a key in InDesign with designated numbers and text. I want the formatting to be like #107, basically like a numbered list (I just manually did it to demonstrate). I tried messing around with bullet/number lists, but I can't seem to find a way to input any number (the numbers do not go in any order).

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this formatting?

Comment: HI @aalok89, welcome to GD.SE. Only with that screenshot it's not possible to see what the problem is. You should include the full paragraph with the hidden characters, it seems the paragraphs are not consecutive. To show the hidden characters: Menu Type > Show Hidden Characters.

Comment: @Danielillo I manually did 107 with just tabs and spaces just to show the visual result I wanted. I want the visual formatting of 107 but with proper settings and methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are only showing a single example of the styling you want using a three digit number. We don't know exactly what you want to happen when there are only two digits or when the number has a different width than the number "107".

I can think of these three (and a few more) approaches:

[image]

I'll show how to make the first one - a standard numbered list with left-aligned numbers.

- You need to make sure that there's only a tab character between the period (or the number if you wish to omit the period) and the text:

  [image]

  In your case, this could be easily done using the *Find/Change* dialog. Simply search for a period followed by a space (not visible on the screenshot) and *Change All* to a period followed by a tab character (\t):

  [image]
- Create a *Character Style* for the numbers of your custom numbered list. In this case it just changes the font weight to *bold*.
- Create a *Paragraph Style* for your custom numbered list.
- Enter *Paragraph Style Options > Drop Caps and Nested Styles* and create this *Nested Style*:

  [image]

  This applies the character style "Number" to every character from the beginning of the paragraph to the first tab character.
- Enter *Paragraph Style Options > Tabs* and make sure that every tab is deleted. You can select one and click *Clear All*. (This is done to make that the tabs doesn't interfere with the indents we are making next.)
- Enter *Paragraph Style Options > Indents and Spacing* and set *Left Indent* to the wanted indent and *First Line Indent* to the negative of that:

  [image]

That's it.